# this.getClass().getResource("").getFile() returning path with "file:" at the beginning when running project with IntelliJ/Jetty 8.1.14

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jetty

I am trying to switch my dev environment from Eclipse to IntelliJ. I am developing a Java EE application that uses the path returned from this.getClass().getResource("").getFile() to create a new FileInputStream. When running the project with Eclipse/Jetty (from the Jetty plugin on the Eclipse marketplace) and on production with Glassfish, the string returned looks like "/C:/path/to/class/in/jar/".

However, when running the project with IntelliJ/Jetty (8.* from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/dist/) the file path returned looks like "file:/C:/path/to/class/in/jar/". The 'file:' at the beginning of the string is causing a FileNotFoundException on "new FileInputStream(path)".

I am developing on Windows 8.

I can easily strip the "file:" from the string, but I would rather not change the codebase to fix what appears to be an environment issue. Is there something I can do so that getFile() does not return a path starting with "file:"?

Comment: I think I've made some progress. IntelliJ is deploying to a .jar file in the target folder. Eclipse is deploying to the target/classes folder, without a jar file. How can I configure IntelliJ to do the same?

Comment: If you are expecting `URL#getFile()` to return a file name, you are doing something seriously wrong. You have no guarantee that the URL returned from `Class#getResource(String)` points to an actual file in the file system.

Comment: The file name is appended to the path returned by `URL#getFile()` before the FileInputStream is initialized. I should have specified that.

Comment: To add, the path from `URL#getFile()` is split on "com", which is the root of the package. The name of the desired folder/file is then appended and the FileInputStream initialized using the new path. I'm open to a better way of doing this.

If it makes me look a little better this is part a large enterprise application that I'm debugging, and I did not do the original implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The application was deploying one of the subprojects to a jar file instead of a folder. This was causing `URL#getFile()` to append the "file:" protocol for some reason. To solve this I went to Module Settings > Artifacts > 'exploded' module and moved the subproject's compile output from the jar file to a folder.

Comment: This is just a work around and not the optimal solution. Like @jarnbjo mentioned in his comments, your approach is not portable.

Comment: You are correct. I have already run into issues with the artifacts being reset after modifying one of the pom.xml files.